# What auto rigging system should I use to rig my character?

Tags: rigging

Rigify is messing up and buggy right from the converting stage.
Makehuman I have to limit my rigs to MHX2 imports. I've tried all the optional import rigs for MHX and they all lack in some measure.
Those are the ones I've tried.
I tried making my own rig but that is problematic as I can't seem to make a rig that is robust enough.
I'd like to find something that will quickly set up a rig ready to do animation with my models.
I'm trying to avoid bottleneck situations where it takes a lot of manual editing just get some aspect done, for example: I'd like to import a BVH in one click instead of having to assign each bone.
I have dozens of models and I'd like to at least get 1 completely working rig per day or sooner.

I'd like to find a rigging system that has the following:

1. Easy to animate FK and IK.
2. Phoneme mouth shapes.
3. Facial Expression controls.
4. Versatile hand controls.
5. Can take BVH input.
6. Versatile ability to use mesh deform or direct weight paint rigging.
7. Ability to easily add spring or jiggle systems.
8. Quickly go from model to rigged character.
9. Mostly biped but if it can do quadrupeds bonus.
10. Cloth simulation bonus.

Answer (score -1):

Have you looked into Auto-Rig Pro(ARP)? It's a purchasable add-on. From the reviews and videos that I have seen, it looks pretty solid.